# Publishing app with Ionic deploy iOS, and android

Tags: ionic-framework, app-store, mobile-development

I am new to app development and have been using the ionic framework to build my app. I am ready to publish, and want to use ionic deploy, as it seems efficient.

My question is do I need to upload my app to Apple/play store before I can use Ionic deploy, or can I use ionic deploy when publishing for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first publish and release your app using the standard store process, [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html) is a good guide to help with it.

Then you can use Ionic Deploy for subsequent deployments / releases.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon. Would you be able to point me in the right direction on how to use in app purchasing with Ionic? I am wanting to use the inAppPurchase2 plugin. But there is minimal documentation

Comment: No sorry @JCHutchinson I haven't touched it before, I've worked with a fair few plugins though so maybe I can help with a specific problem you are having?

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I think I just need to spend more time understanding the whole in app purchase procedures for iOS, and Android. That should clear things up.